# Почему не отображаются записи модели?

Tags: django

Так вышло что пока я чинил одно у меня сломалось другое, и то что до этого работало и то в чём у меня были самые большие надежды вдруг сломалось, причём дело в том что код изменялся без затрагивания этой модели, по этому проблема привела меня в ступор, сначала я пытался создать отдельный класс в вьюшке который был бы чисто для этой модели и для её записей но меня это ни к чему не привело, потом я пытался переименовать модель, потом поигрался с хтмл но в итоге безрезультатно, сразу скажу модель зарегистрирована всё миграции сделаны, так же при команде `python manage.py sqlmigrate Homepage 0001` таблица с моделью создаётся, по этому и привела в ступор,  вроде всё норм но не выводит, возможно я где-то не доглядел что я не отрицаю, и проблема окажется ну уж до жути лёгкой.

Вот код views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    numbers = Number.objects.all()
    context['numbers'] = numbers
    return context
```

Вот код models.py

```
class Number(models.Model):
number1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
number2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.number1_text + self.number2_text
```

Вот код urls.py(хз зачем ну вдруг понадобится)

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
app_name = 'Homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('Home', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('sale', views.sale, name='sale'),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='media/images/logo1.png', permanent=True)),
]
```

Вот код хтмл

```html
<div class="modal-body">
           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{number.number1_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}

           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{numbers.number2_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}

          </div>
```

Что ещё скидывать даже не знаю, так что если что-то понадобится пишите, я добавлю

Comment: также вся мистика в том что остальные записи других моделей остались целыми только эта не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вместо numbers:

```
numbers.number2_text
```

Должен быть number:

```
number.number2_text
```

Попробуй в шаблоне:

```html
{% for number in numbers %}
  <h3 class="numbers">{{ number.number1_text }}</h3>
  <h3 class="numbers">{{ number.number2_text }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Ещё, нет смысла переопределять **str**:

```py
class Number(models.Model):
    number1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.number1_text + self.number2_text
```

Comment: Что-то странное происходит, изменил на ваш код теперь выбивает ошибку `no such table: Homepage_number`

Comment: Это конечно ничего, так как не первый раз сталкиваюсь с этой ошибкой, но ничего кроме как пересоздать проект до этого не помогало

Comment: Я. кажется, понял, в чём твоя ошибка, у тебя класс модели назван `Numbers` а не `Number`, а во вьюхе ты пишешь `Number.objects.all()`. Потому предлагаю переименовать класс в `Number` и снова сделать миграции.

Comment: Тогда у тебя будет создана нужная таблица Homepage_number

Comment: Про `Numbers` в моделях прошу прощения это результаты моих экспериментов так-то исходник с `Number` был прописан, и это я изменил. Можете просмотреть обновленный код. Хотя и смотреть там особо нечего. Плюс если была проблема с миграциями то мне бы выдало что такой таблицы не существует.
Также в вопросе я добавил что при команде `py manage.py sqlmigrate Homepage 0001` таблица создаётся

Comment: `no such table: Homepage_number` говорит, что проблема как раз в таблице. Сделай миграции так:
`py manage.py makemigrations`, затем `py manage.py migrate`.

Comment: миграции сделаны, проблему с `no such table: Homepage_number` я решил ещё вчера. А если ещё раз запустить миграции просто говорит что нету не примененных миграций